# PowerShell start-job Robocopy Log parameter issue

Tags: multithreading, powershell, logging, robocopy

I made a function that must return a job running robocopy in power shell but there is an issue with the log parameter:

This works :

```
function RunRobocopyJob { param ([object]$pSynchronization)   

    $logPath = $pSynchronization.logPath

    return Start-Job -ScriptBlock { robocopy $using:pSynchronization.source $using:pSynchronization.destination /MIR /PURGE /LOG:$using:logPath }
}
```

But this does not :

```
function RunRobocopyJob { param ([object]$pSynchronization)   

    return Start-Job -ScriptBlock { robocopy $using:pSynchronization.source $using:pSynchronization.destination /MIR /PURGE /LOG:$using:pSynchronization.logPath }
}
```

I can tell that something is missing in the second case because Powershell ISE "logPath" property is colored violet insted of black, with means it is not interpreted as an object property like the others.
I thinck that's because it is next to "/LOG:"

So my question is : what is the correct syntax to make it work ?

Comment: Give `/LOG:($using:pSynchronization.logPath)` a shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sadly it does not work either

But Powershell ISE is now showing the right syntax coloring

Comment: I think the issue here is the use of `$using:`. I suggest you to declare `$pSynchronization = $using:pSynchronization` and then use `$pSynchronization.source`; `$pSynchronization.logpath` etc.

Comment: you're absolutly right : 4using is what causes the issue
But the point here is to not have to declare something intermediate : the first option works fine.
I really want to find the syntax that allows me to do it in one line